# Concatenate a long list of character in R

Tags: r

I would like to concatenated a long list of characters like this

```
d  <- tm_map(d , removeWords, c("año","años","mes","meses","mil","miles",
                            "millon","millones", "diez", "cien", 
                            "doscientos", "san", "bío", "alta", "alto",
                            "100", "113", "200", "300", "400", "450",
                            "2006", "2010", "2014", "2015","2016", 
                            "2017", "2018", "marzo", "mayo", "ciento",
                            "cientos","mitad"))
```

but then a error appear :

Error: unexpected ',' in ""cientos","

so aparently the onli solution is concatenate all the characters in just one line but is so ugly

```
d  <- tm_map(d , removeWords, c("año","años","mes","meses","mil","miles","millon","millones", "diez", "cien",..
```

there is not another way?

thanks

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between these two "approaches", it seems like you have some syntax error (i.e., additional `"` or something like that)

Comment: look at `stringr`package with the function `str_c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
d=removeWords(tolower(d),c("año","años","mes","meses","mil","miles",
                                "millon","millones", "diez", "cien", 
                                "doscientos", "san", "bío", "alta", "alto",
                                "100", "113", "200", "300", "400", "450",
                                "2006", "2010", "2014", "2015","2016", 
                                "2017", "2018", "marzo", "mayo", "ciento",
                                "cientos","mitad"))
```

instead of tm_map